# USB port stays powered after shutdown, since laptop overheated some time ago

Tags: laptop, usb, overheating

My laptop has 4 USB ports: two USB 2, and two USB 3.

It overheated for the first time a week ago (after an intensive gaming session), and one of my USB 3 ports, where I plug in my mouse, is now permanently powered, even after shutdown.

I looked into the BIOS/UEFI settings, but the "USB Charger" option is disabled.

The remaining ports are powered off after shutdown.

Strangely, my laptop overheated the day after the warranty's ended.

Thanks in advance for your answer(s).

Comment: Try unplugging the laptop from the power, pull the battery out and then press the power button on the laptop a couple of times,  This will discharge the mainboard and remaining power in the PSU.  Plug everything back in and see what happens.

Comment: Is that port a yellow one ? There are USB ports which can be set to always provide power even if the laptop is powered off.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: No, it's a blue one.

Comment: @StBlade: I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will quote [StBlade's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/947455/usb-port-stays-powered-after-laptop-overheat#comment1291180_947455), since his solution worked for me:

> Try unplugging the laptop from the power, pull the battery out and
> then press the power button on the laptop a couple of times, This will
> discharge the mainboard and remaining power in the PSU. Plug
> everything back in and see what happens.

Thanks again, StBlade.

EDIT: It seems this solution is temporary.